# Vagrant up - The box 'ubuntu/vivid64' could not be found

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

On vagrant up keep getting this error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'ubuntu/vivid64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'ubuntu/vivid64' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Atlas, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/vivid64"]
Error: The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
```

I suggest that something is wrong with url, but don't know how to solve it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also try the larryli/vivid64 box.

https://vagrantcloud.com/larryli/boxes/vivid64

Comment: could you please elaborate, how to change the url.

Answer (score 2):

One of the solutions to this is to allow the insecure download, worked for me to download the box

Add this in Vagrantfile
  config.vm.box_download_insecure = true

Answer (score 1):

That box doesn't exist - the url returns a 404. Try a different one, like https://atlas.hashicorp.com/ubuntu/boxes/wily64

Comment: This box existed for me before, and now doesn't. The entire point of Vagrant for me is to make the VMs reproducible from developer to developer and from date to date. Kinda defeats the purpose, if the underlying box just vanishes to thin air..

Comment: You can always take your own snapshots if you want to share an initial box state.

Comment: I was kinda hoping that the boxes would be hosted "forever", but good point on having the ability to take control and probably publish the initial box state as a "different box".

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of the following steps:

1. Replace in the Vagrantfile by this (find equivalent definitions)

   Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
     config.vm.box = "larryli/vivid64"
   end
2. Remove Vagrantfile and create a new one.

   rm Vagranfile
    vagrant init larryli/vivid64
    vagrant up